# Autofill HTML form field with number on page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, autocomplete

Is there a way using JS to autofill a HTML form field with a number pre-existing on the page, example below:

So the '123456' number would populate in form field onload.

[image]

Comment: I would help if you showed relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Once the DOM is loaded grab the input using the DOM's api and set its value to 123456 or whatever else you want it to be, i.e.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("my_input").value = 123456;
});
```

However, if you always want it to start of holding a specific value, why not just make use of the `value` attribute, which will also show when users have JavaScript disabled:

```
<input type="text" value="123456">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     var accountNumberSpan = $('#accountNumber').text();
     $('#myId').val(accountNumberSpan.substr(accountNumberSpan.indexOf(":") + 1));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="accountNumber">Account Number: 12345</span>

<br />
<input type="text" name="myName" id="myId" value="" />
```